# Cordova not making ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, html-framework-7

I am making a Cordova app with Framework7.
I want to make an ajax call to a file which is on my localhost.
When I am hitting ajax URL of localhost on my web browser I am getting the result perfectly as I wanted.
But when I try to make an ajax call through Cordova app in Android Studio emulator it fails.

I guess it has something to do with `config.xml` file of Cordova.
Below is my full confix.xml content:-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="http://*" />
    <access origin="https://*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
</widget>
```

My Ajax Script:-

```
var ajax_url = "http://10.0.2.2/";

jQuery(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:ajax_url+'api.php/getMenu', 
        type:'post',        
        success:function(response)      
         {          
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);          
            response = response.payload; 
            var html = '<ul>';
                jQuery(response).each(function(index,value){
                    htmlpage_name = value.title.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
                    html+='<li>';
                    if (!/^(f|ht)tps?:\/\//i.test(value.link)) {
                        html+='<a href="'+htmlpage_name+'.html" class="item-link"><div class="item-content"> <div class="item-inner"> <div class="item-title">'+value.title+'</div></div></div></a>';
                     }
                    else
                    {
                        html+='<a href="'+value.link+'.html" class="item-link"><div class="item-content"> <div class="item-inner"> <div class="item-title">'+value.title+'</div></div></div></a>';
                    }

                    html+='</li>';
                });
                html+='<li><a href="barcodescan.html" class="item-link"><div class="item-content"> <div class="item-inner"> <div class="item-title">Barcode Scan</div></div></div></li>';
                html+='</ul>';
               jQuery(".home-page-menu").html(html);        }
    }); });
```

Things I tried :-

1) Added access origin in `confix.xml` file.

```
 <access origin="*" />
 <access origin="http://*" />
 <access origin="https://*" />
```

2) Added header in my php file where i am making ajax call.

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS");
```

3) Added `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag in `index.html`.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Please help me out in sorting this.

Comment: Try adding a connect-src section with * value (or just the ip), or put * in the default-src

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is "this computer", so when you try from the computer browser it works.
But the emulator is a virtual machine running in your computer, so localhost is the emulator itself, not your computer, and the emulator doesn't have a server inside so the ajax call fails.

The simulator has an IP that points to the "localhost" of the computer running it, that's `10.0.2.2` Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html)

So you can use that IP instead of localhost, but then it won't work on the computer browser. Also, it won't work on a real device.

Best thing you can do is to use the local IP of your machine, that will work on the browser, the simulator and on any device on the same local network as your computer. It will be something like `192.168.1.xx`

Comment: I didn't know this before got to learn new thing, thanks for explaining clearly.I tried, it is not working.I am pretty sure there isn't fault in my script because when I user my Live server IP it works perfectly, but not with localhost.
I am adding ajax script to my question please have a look.